# ARC does not release CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I have a code block which aims to capture snapshot of pdf based custom views for each page. To accomplish it I'll create view controller in a loop and then iterate. The problem is even view controller released custom view doesn't released and look like live on Instruments tool. As a result for loop iterates a lot so it breaks the memory (up to 500MB for 42 living) and crashes.
Here is the iteration code;

```
do
    {
        __pageDictionary = CFDictionaryGetValue(_allPages,
                                                __pageID);
        CUIPageViewController *__pageViewController = [self _pageWithID:__pageID];
        [__pageViewController addMainLayers];
        [[APP_DELEGATE assetManager] temporarilyPasteSnapshotSource:__pageViewController.view];
        UIImage *__snapshotImage = [__pageViewController captureSnapshot];
        [[AOAssetManager sharedManager] saveImage:__snapshotImage
                             forPublicationBundle:_publicationTileViewController.publication.bundle
                                           pageID:(__bridge NSString *)__pageID];
        [[APP_DELEGATE assetManager] removePastedSnapshotSource:__pageViewController.view];
                __snapshotImage = nil;
        __pageViewController = nil;

        ind += 6 * 0.1 / CFDictionaryGetCount(_allPages);
    }
    while (![(__bridge NSString *)(__pageID = CFDictionaryGetValue(__pageDictionary,
                                                                   kMFMarkupKeyPageNextPageID)) isMemberOfClass:[NSNull class]]);
    _generatingSnapshots = NO;
```

And here the captureSnapshot method;

```
- (UIImage *)captureSnapshot
{
    CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return capturedImage;
}
```

Instruments;

[image]

Edit for further details:

Below code is from CUIPDFView a subclass of UIView;

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self drawInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
}

-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{

    CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y,self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0f);
    CGContextFillRect(context, drawRect);

    // PDF page drawing expects a Lower-Left coordinate system, so we flip the coordinate system
    // before we start drawing.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Grab the first PDF page
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(_pdfDocument, _pageNumberToUse);
    // We're about to modify the context CTM to draw the PDF page where we want it, so save the graphics state in case we want to do more drawing
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    // CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform provides an easy way to get the transform for a PDF page. It will scale down to fit, including any
    // base rotations necessary to display the PDF page correctly.
    CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFCropBox, self.bounds, 0, true);
    // And apply the transform.
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);
    // Finally, we draw the page and restore the graphics state for further manipulations!
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}
```

When I delete drawRect method implementation, memory allocation problem dismiss but obviously it can't print the pdf.

Comment: Have you run the Static Analyser against your project. It's very good for spotting memory problems with using Core Foundation objects.

Comment: yeap already did it but issues not related.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an @autoreleasepool inside your loop:

```
do
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        __pageDictionary = CFDictionaryGetValue(_allPages,
                                            __pageID);
        CUIPageViewController *__pageViewController = [self _pageWithID:__pageID];
        [__pageViewController addMainLayers];
        [[APP_DELEGATE assetManager] temporarilyPasteSnapshotSource:__pageViewController.view];
        UIImage *__snapshotImage = [__pageViewController captureSnapshot];
        [[AOAssetManager sharedManager] saveImage:__snapshotImage
                         forPublicationBundle:_publicationTileViewController.publication.bundle
                                       pageID:(__bridge NSString *)__pageID];
        [[APP_DELEGATE assetManager] removePastedSnapshotSource:__pageViewController.view];
            __snapshotImage = nil;
        __pageViewController = nil;

        ind += 6 * 0.1 / CFDictionaryGetCount(_allPages);
    }
}
while (![(__bridge NSString *)(__pageID = CFDictionaryGetValue(__pageDictionary,
```

This will flush the autorelease pool each time through the loop, releasing all the autoreleased objects.

Comment: it removed the CG Raster Data memory allocation but the first one CUIPDFView(CALayer) memory part increased to 600MB from 300MB. Conclusion couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if this is actually a problem with ARC.  An object that is still alive still has a strong reference to the layer.

1. What does [AOAssetManager saveImage:...] do with the image.  Are you sure it is not holding onto it?
2. Is _pageWithID: doing something that is keeping a pointer to CUIPageViewController around?

Comment: first one is saving uiimage. pageWithId is for allocation of CUIPageViewController at first time and then returns it.